# Advanced Access Manager: RESTful endpoint to refresh token

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I'm using Advanced Access Manager (AAM) plugin, and have been trying to refresh a still valid JWT token using the `/aam/v1/refresh-jwt` RESTful endpoing, however I’m getting the following error:

```
“rest_jwt_validation_failure”: [“Wrong number of segments”]
```

The way I’m calling the endpoint is as follows:

```
POST {{Base URL}}/wp-json/aam/v1/authenticate
HEADERS Authentication: Bearer {{token}}
```

Any though on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you need to POST the token as a 'jwt' property in a JSON object, the same way you'd POST it to the validate endpoint:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://dev.wordpress/wp-json/aam/v1/refresh-jwt \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "jwt": "0yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NDM4OTExNjQsImV4cCI6MTU0Mzk3NzU2NCwidXNlcklkIjoxfQ.0wGIbcTDH5yWSsdStZFct_-auyOFJqf3NKQasTCs4QU"
}'
```

(based on https://forum.aamplugin.com/d/4-how-to-validate-jwt-token)

It doesn't look like this code reads the token from the Authorization header (and it's 'Authorization' not 'Authentication').

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I wasn't really sending the token in the right way :P